# Need a formula to calculate a sum in a column if a condition is met

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

I have a spreadsheet for work that we manually update in 30 minute intervals. I would like to create a formula where it will calculate a Sum of one column only after a value is entered in a second column. The 1st column is a forecasted amount. The second column is the actual. How do i get it to Sum the forecasted amount automatically after I enter a value in the actuals column. I do not know if it should be an IF and Then statement a DSUm or a SUMIF. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you are after. But from the sound of it, you want SUMIF not COUNTIF. COUNTIF appears to count the number of cells from a given range of cells that satisfies the conditions. SUMIF does a sum of the values within those cells. Here's more info:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/countif-HP005209029.aspx

http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/sumif-HP005209292.aspx